# while executing this query i got an error message like subquery returns more than one value

Tags: mysql, sql

I got an error message

> subquery returns more than one value

```
SELECT title,booking_date 
    FROM services,user_booking
    where services.id=(
    select service_id from user_booking where user_id in 
    (
    select distinct id from users where users.email='test')
    )
```

Comment: while executing this query got an erro subquery returns more than one value..

Comment: The title should have the summary of your problem and not the first line of your problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `=` condition, you have to make sure that your subquery only returns 1 row. Otherwise, use the `in` condition.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I got the answer